# Error to convert varchar to float using c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datatable, casting

I have a problem , i'm trying to do operations between values recorded(type float) in table of data , the problem is when i try to update value(result of the operation in textbox)  in datable using combobox after maintaining opération , it shows me error (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error converting data type varchar to float.'), So how can i resolve that !help please

This is a part a of my code in which the error exists

```
private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        String query = "UPDATE Table_com SET Contents='" + textBox6.Text + "' WHERE Variable='" + comboBox5.Text + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table_com where Variable='" + comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Variable mise à jour avec succés");

    }
```

Comment: Post the value that seems to produce the error.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the Table you're trying to update (i.e. the Create Statement)? And by the way: Use CommandParameter instead of putting values from UI directly into the Query String. That might lead to serious security issues (SQL Injection)

Comment: If the SQL field you're trying to update is a float then you can not use Field='1' as that is a varchar, you have to use Field=1 instead (no apostrophes). Also never directly put variables into SQL statements and use [prepared statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.8) instead otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: *Don't* create queries by concatenating strings. Imagine what would happen if someone typed `' where 1=0; drop table Table_sagemcom;--` in the textbox. Use parameterized queries to pass strongly-typed variables

Comment: Your code executes the SELECT query *twice* but never does anything with the results. First with `ExecuteNonQuery` which doesn't return any results and then with `da.Fill` which loads a datatable but never uses it for anything. Do you really need that query or datatable?

Comment: @Torben Schramme  you mena that  ?                                                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-VEFPLGG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");

Comment: @Longoon12000 , you mean i need to delete ' ' , i did it butit gives me an error (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax for keyword' WHERE '.')

Comment: @Belb to understand your query you could add a breakpoint after String query = ... and then copy the actual content of your query string and run this query manually in SQL. This could at least help you understand what the syntax error in your query is and how to fix it.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos , can you give me an example please ?it's not completed yet I will use them later but the error is related to the first 5 lines .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use float integer etc. values like text field as:

```cs
String query = "UPDATE Table_com SET Contents='" + textBox6.Text + "' WHERE Variable='" + comboBox5.Text + "'";
```

and your code really risky, you may use parameters like this, dont use string and convert your value to float :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ConnectionString = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                String query = "UPDATE Table_com SET Contents=@contents WHERE Variable=@variable";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@contents", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@variable", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox5.Text;

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: i didn't understand why i have to convert comboBox5 , its type is correct (varchar) the, problem is in textbox, i tried your method but it gives me same error of conversion!

Comment: where is your problem an then convert it. I gave you example. if your text box has float value 123.123 convert it to float and use it as float.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i tried refering to wikiCan answer

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-VEFPLGG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");    
 private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String query = "UPDATE Table_com SET Contents=@contents ";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@contents", SqlDbType.Float).Value = textBox6.Text;
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@variable", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble(comboBox5.Text);

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: try convert to float.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@contents", SqlDbType.Float).Value =Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);

Comment: That is what I try to complete. so ok.